# Run functions.php snippet only targeting frontend

Tags: wordpress

So i have the following snippet in my functions.php:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'product');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

This will only show products when a user searches for something. But it also affects the search in de admin area. how can i ensure that it only targets front-end?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it like that :

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'product');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!